# Computed height of absolute positioned element

Tags: javascript, css

I am having trouble reading absolute positioned element height.

My primarily goal is to set another DIV which will fade black background to fill whole page, but I am going nowhere...

I tried `document.body.scrollWidth`, but that works only in beginning of loading stage. When main DIV loads, it takes more space than fading one, and there is space, in bottom, that hasn't been filled with fading DIV element.

Can someone help?

```
div#main_theater{
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #EEE4B9;
    width: 940px;
    opacity: 1; 
    z-index: 100;
}
div#blackOut{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Here is working (in a start):

```
var picHeight = document.body.scrollWidth;
blackOut = document.createElement('div');
blackOut.setAttribute('id','blackOut');
blackOut.style.height = picHeight + 'px';
```

And after AJAX call to PHP script, I get new size of window. New size is bigger by `div#main_theater` and its greater then old `div#blackOut`.

```
if(document.getElementById('main_theater')){    
    blackOut.style.height = document.getElementById('main_theater').style.height;
}
```

When AJAX call finish, `div#main_theater` is bigger than previous body height. Also, I tried to do reading scrollHeight/offsetHeight after re-flow, after AJAX call, and numbers are the same as before(?)...

EDIT: It is possible that AJAX responseText load a document, but next command, in JS, is too fast to capture real document size on image load. In my opinion, image is not in so short time loaded, therefor size of document can't be properly readed.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: Code is massive, but I try to simple it out..

Comment: You only tagged this `css`, I'm assuming you are intending to do this in `javascript` so I am adding that tag.  The more accurately you tag your questions, the better your results will be.

Comment: Have you tried obtaining the height with jQuery? You don't need jQuery obviously, but I think they've already struggled with this kind of issue, so if it works for them, you can have a look at how they did it.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use fixed positioning. Something like this:

```
<style>
div#totaldude {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
    $("body").append("div id='totaldude'></div>"); 
    $("#totaldude").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
</script>
```